# Flip order of characters within a string using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I wish to flip the order of characters within the 'date' column using Python

**Data**

```
id  type  date
aa  hi    2022 Q1
aa  hi    2022 Q2
```

**Desired**

```
id  type    date
aa  hi      Q1 2022
aa  hi      Q2 2022
```

**Doing**

I believe I can separate and then reverse them?

```
a = df.split()
```

Any suggestion is helpful

Comment: Well yeah that's exactly what you'd do. split the string, reverse the list of substrings, and join again.

Comment: `df['date'].str.split()`

Comment: ok will do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, I would do it with list comprehension:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2022 Q1','2022 Q2']})
df['date'] = [' '.join(x.split()[::-1]) for x in df['date']]
```

Using `print(df['date'])` Outputs:

```
0    Q1 2022
1    Q2 2022
```

Comment: It can't be done directly in pandas with `df['date'].str.split()`?

Comment: ok thnk you @celius will output include the columns  and headers as well

Comment: @Barmar I'm unsure if the `split()` function allows for order reversal.
@Lynn yes of course, I have only printed the column of interest.

Comment: OP requires the columns to be split, reversed in order and then joined back into a single string, I don't that can be achieved only with `.str.split()` that's why I need to use `[::-1]` for order reversal and `' '.join()` for each element split and reversed.

Comment: Hi @Barmar I tried  df['date'].str.split(), but did not get desired result

Comment: That's just the start of it -- you have to reverse them and join them back together.

Comment: oh  yes ok thank you @Barmar

Answer (score 3):

We can use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with capture groups if wanting to be explicit on pattern:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].str.replace(r'^(\d{4}) (Q\d)$', r'\2 \1', regex=True)
```

Or with several `str` calls ([`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html), [`str.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html)), but this can be slow as it requires several copies of data:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].str.split().str[::-1].str.join(' ')
```

`df`:

```
   id type     date
0  aa   hi  Q1 2022
1  aa   hi  Q2 2022
```

---

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['aa', 'aa'],
    'type': ['hi', 'hi'],
    'date': ['2022 Q1', '2022 Q2']
})
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df["date"] = df["date"].apply(lambda x: " ".join(reversed(x.split())))
```

output:

```
0    Q1 2022
1    Q2 2022
```

Comment: I you don't need to call `list()`. The argment to `join()` can be any iterable.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Series.map` + `str.format`

```
# split each date on the whitespace and unpacks the resulting list
df['date'] = df['date'].map(lambda date: "{1} {0}".format(*date.split()))
```

**Output**

```
>>> df['date']

0    Q1 2022
1    Q2 2022
Name: date, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```py
df.assign(date = df.date
                   .str
                   .split()
                   .str[::-1]
                   .str
                   .join(' ')
             )

   id type     date
0  aa   hi  Q1 2022
1  aa   hi  Q2 2022
```